# SQL Server fulltext search does not return all the results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I tried to use full-text search for a table called "Business" in SQL Server 2008. Here is the statement (the search term is in Chinese).

```
select * from Business biz where CONTAINS(biz.*,'家具')
```

And then I use like statement to do the same

```
select * from Business where Name like '%家具%'
```

The full-text search returns 8 results and the like search returns 9 results which is what I expected. Does anyone know what might cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the Chinese language, so I can't say for sure, but here's my best guess.

SQL Server's fulltext searching is word based, while LIKE is looking for character patterns within a string. As an example in English, a CONTAINS search for "warn" would not find the word "forewarned", but a LIKE for '%warn%' would.

Comment: it is exactly the case as you described. sql sever 2008 is not very good at full-text search with chinese. I changed my full-text engine to lucene.net, it works perfectly without any problem.

Comment: @wschenkai: Glad to hear you found a solution. Would you be willing to mark this answer as accepted?